# Cannot connect to AWS RDS PostgreSQL with Golang using Helm Charts

Tags: postgresql, go, rds, kubernetes-helm

I am unable to connect to AWS RDS PostgeSQL when running Helm Chart for a Go App (GORM). All credentials are stored in a kubernetes secret, and the secret is being used in the helm chart.

Few Points:

- Able to connect locally just fine.
- The PostgreSQL database is already created in RDS, and made sure that the kubernetes secret as matches with the same creds.
- Docker image is pushed and pulled from Gitlab without any errors.
- Command "helm ls" displays the deployment status as "DEPLOYED"
- When taking "kubectl get pod", I get STATUS as "CrashLoopBackoff"
- When taking "kubectl describe pod", I get back MESSAGE "Back-off restarting failed container"
- I then take "kubectl logs pod_name" to track the error, and get back the following:

  1. failed to connect to the database
  2. dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused
     (Not sure why it is still specifying "127.0.0.1" when i have the secret mounted)
- Unable to exec into the pod because it is not running.

I have tried:

- Secure a connection in the same cluster from a different pod using psql to ensure that the creds in the secret are in sync with what was set up in RDS PostgreSQL
- Changing the api from DB_HOST, to host=%s
- Tried connecting using fmt.Sprintf, as well as os.Getenv

"Versions"

**GO** version:

go1.11.1 darwin/amd64

**DOCKER** version:

Client:
 Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.38

API.GO (file)

```
package controllers

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
    _ "gitlab.torq.trans.apps.ge.com/503081542/torq-auth-api/models"
)
var err error
type API struct {
    Database *gorm.DB
    Router   *mux.Router
}

func (api *API) Initialize(opts string) {

    // Initialize DB
    dbinfo := os.Getenv("DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, 
DB_PORT sslmode=disable")
    // dbinfo := os.Getenv("host=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s port=%s sslmode=disable")
    api.Database, err = gorm.Open("postgres", dbinfo)

    if err != nil {
        log.Print("failed to connect to the database")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Bind to a port and pass our router in
    // log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", handlers.CORS() . 
  (api.Router)))

    fmt.Println("Connection established")
    log.Printf("Postgres started at %s PORT", config.DB_PORT)
    // MODELS
    type application struct {
        ID        string    `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
        CreatedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
        UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
        Name      string    `json:"name"`
        Ci        string    `json:"ci"`
    }
    type Cloud struct {
        ID   string `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
        Name string `json:"name"`
    }
    fmt.Println("Tables are created")
    // Enable this line for DB logging
    api.Database.LogMode(true)}

// Initialize Router
    api.Router = mux.NewRouter()
    api.Router.HandleFunc("/api/v1/applications", 
api.HandleApplications)
    api.Router.HandleFunc("/api/v1/application/{id}", 
api.HandleApplication)
    api.Router.HandleFunc("/api/v1/clusters", api.handleClusters)
}
```

I am not exactly sure where the issue could be here, this is a learning experience for myself. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `os.Getenv` only gets a single environment variable at a time, so I don't think your `os.Getenv("DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, 
DB_PORT sslmode=disable")` line does what you expect

Comment: Can you include the relevant part of the Deployment spec that shows where you set the environment variables?

Comment: When setting up a database in RDS, the default parameter group for postgres15 (default.postgres15) is used. However, we need to change the 'rds.force_ssl' parameter, which isn't editable in the default.postgres15 group. To do this, we'll create a new parameter group for postgres15, which allows us to make edits. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76899023/rds-while-connection-error-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host

Answer (score 0):

I think your database initialization code is not doing what you want. Try something like this

```
var driver = "postgres"
var name = os.Getenv("DB_NAME")
var host = os.Getenv("DB_HOST")
var user = os.Getenv("DB_USER")
var pass = os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD")
var conn = fmt.Sprintf("host=%v user=%v password=%v dbname=%v sslmode=disable", host, user, pass, name)
api.Database, err := gorm.Open(driver, conn)
```

Comment: @Wombat Thank you! I will try that out and circle back around.

Comment: I have ade the modification that you suggested above, and the container STATUS is now "CrashLoopBackOff". It initially started off as "Running", and changed minutes later. When I check the logs, I get "dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused". So it has not successfully connected to rds, that would be my next check.

Comment: Did you actually set the environment variables for your container? You are not going to be running postgres in the same container, so 127.0.0.1 is a wrong address.

Comment: You need to set the DB_HOST to your RDS instance DNS name

Comment: They were all created in RDS, and were mounted in the kubernetes secret. The secret was used in the helm chart. Am I understanding you question correctly?

Comment: Host "127.0.01" is not what it is set as in RDS, so not sure how its pulling that

Comment: Yes, the host is currently set to the DNS name

Comment: Well, you can try to use kubectl exec to get a prompt inside the container and see what the environment looks like on the inside

Comment: Or you would be able to if your container was running. Maybe add a custom command to it, so it doesn't fail immediately.

Comment: It worked, but here is what I did to get it to work:

Comment: - Create an ec2 and entered it
- Copied the GO project to that ec2
- Navigated to the GO project in the ec2
- Set the environment variables in the ec2 (export DB_HOST=……export DB_USER=…., etc)
- Ran the code, and it worked. Verified that RDS PostgreSQL connectivity incremented

If I come along any other information that would help clarify, I will add it.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Well, yes, that will work. In a container environment, like kubernetes, you need to set the environment inside the container. In kubernetes you can do that with container template definition for your deployment or replicaset or whatever you are using.

Comment: In regular docker you can do it with a `-e` flag and with docker compose with an `environment:` keyword

Comment: Noted. Will definately do that when it comes to it.