# RDS while connection error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I need assistance as I'm having trouble connecting to a managed Postgres database on RDS. I'm encountering the following error message: "no pg_hba.conf entry for host '16.151.149.51', user 'analytics', database 'database', no encryption" I have confirmed that encryption is functioning properly, and I've also added the IP to the security groups. What steps should I take to resolve this issue?

Comment: "I have confirmed that encryption is functioning properly,"  What specifically did you do?  I wouldn't think it is possible to do that if you can't even establish a connection in the first place.

Comment: The error message means the client requested a connection without ssl, and the server refused.  Presumably that means rds.force_ssl is set to 1.

Comment: I changed the rds.force_ssl to be 0 and I got the same error msg

Comment: Are you sure your change has taken effect, and that you are connecting the same serve as the one you made the change for?  I don't see how you could get this particular error message any other way on RDS.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

First of all I wanna note that Nick's answer resolved my issue, but I just would love to add a detailed steps to follow for those who's new to AWS:

### Create a New Parameter Group:

1. Open the Amazon RDS console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose "Parameter groups".
3. Click "Create parameter group" at the top right of the page.
4. In the "Parameter group family" dropdown, select "postgres15".
5. In the "Group name" field, enter a name for the new parameter group.
6. In the "Description" field, enter a description for the new parameter group.
7. Click "Create" at the bottom right of the page.

### Modify the rds.force_ssl Parameter of your new Parameter Group:

1. In the list of parameter groups, click on the name of the new parameter group you just created.
2. In the "Filter parameters" box, type rds.force_ssl and press Enter.
3. You should see the rds.force_ssl parameter. Click "Edit parameters".
4. Change the value of rds.force_ssl from 1 to 0, then click "Save changes".

### Associate Your RDS Instance with the New Parameter Group:

1. In the navigation pane, choose "Databases".
2. Click on the name of your RDS instance.
3. Click "Modify" at the top right of the page.
4. In the "Database options" section, find the "DB parameter group" setting and select the new parameter group you created from the dropdown menu.
5. Scroll down and click "Continue".
6. Review the summary of modifications and click "Modify DB Instance".

### Reboote Your RDS Instance:

1. In the navigation pane, choose "Databases".
2. Click on the name of your RDS instance.
3. Click "Actions" at the top right of the page, then "Reboot".
4. Confirm that you want to reboot the instance.

By following these steps, you should be able to successfully modify the rds.force_ssl parameter in your Amazon RDS instance. And hopefully the connection issue would be resolved.

Comment: why to lower the security? why rds.force_ssl from 1 to 0?  
We should figure out how to make it work when ssl is enabled.

Answer (score 29):

If you're using Engine 15 or higher:

When setting up a database in RDS, the default parameter group for postgres15 (default.postgres15) is used. However, we need to change the 'rds.force_ssl' parameter, which isn't editable in the default.postgres15 group. To do this, we'll create a new parameter group for postgres15, which allows us to make edits.

Once the new parameter group is created, we'll select it and find the 'rds.force_ssl' parameter. We'll change its value from 1 to 0 (the default is 1).

Then, in the database configuration tab, we'll switch the 'DB instance parameter group' from the default group to the new one.

After making these changes, we'll reboot the database and try connecting again. This should work.

Answer (score 16):

```
new Pool({
        user: "",
        password: "",
        host: "",
        database: "",
        port: "",
        ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
})
```

For node Postgres

Comment: Anyone can give an explanation ?

Comment: This works, but if any one with more security knowledge could chime in on the consequences of this, that'd be very helpful.

Comment: https://node-postgres.com/features/ssl this may help you.

Answer (score 3):

Piggybacking off of [Nikhil P K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22055567/nikhil-p-k)'s answer, this CDK code will turn SSL off for Postgres 15+:

```
    const engine = DatabaseInstanceEngine.postgres({
      version: PostgresEngineVersion.VER_15,
    });

    const parameterGroup = new ParameterGroup(
      this,
      "parameter-group",
      {
        engine,
        parameters: {
          "rds.force_ssl": "0",
        },
      }
    );

    this.database = new DatabaseInstance(this, "database", {
      engine,
      parameterGroup,
      // ...the rest of the setup
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, OP might have resolved the issue already but for others who come across this: ensure you have the AWS RDS CA certificates downloaded and double-check that your credentials are correct. In my case the Terraform module I used had `manage_master_user_password` set to true by default which nicely silently discarded my provided password and set it on its own.

But basically, for the unaware, the steps to connect using SSL is:

1. Create RDS that is either publicly accessible (eg `publicly_accessible = true` in TF) or open to at least your VPC subnets with the proper ingress rules eg:

```
  ingress {
    from_port   = 5432
    to_port     = 5432
    protocol    = "tcp"
    description = "PostgreSQL access for VPC and local machine"
    cidr_blocks = [
      module.vpc.vpc_cidr_block,
      "1.1.1.1/32"
    ]
  }
```

2. Then in your ec2-instance / client, download the needed root CAs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html Global is the easiest eg: `curl -O https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem`
3. Create `.postgresql` folder wherever Postgres wants it and move the certs there as `root.crt` eg: `mv global-bundle.pem /root/.postgresql/root.crt`
4. Connect using the proper connection string with SSL enforced eg: `psql postgresql://<your user>:<your pass>@postgres-1-project.z4dadjt5qxpn.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/<your db>?sslmode=verify-full`
5. You should be connected to your RDS. If it says `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user` check your credentials again. SSL should work (or at least complain something) if you have it set to `verify-full`

Comment: How does one figure out "wherever Postgres wants it"?

Comment: It should say in the error message. Eg if you have installed it with root, /root/.postgresql

Comment: How can you set this if you are calling from a node app locally?

Comment: This is the solution I actually needed to connect to my new RDS, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just want to share my experience with this problem in the last couple of days

after trying all the suggested solutions the problem was wrong "Master username "

i have been copied the correct Master username from Configuration tab on aws RDS and it is successfully worked :)

Comment: I am using IAM token authentication, and received this error because I had recreated my database but forgot to update the IAM Policy with the new database ID

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the voted answer is to change the client instead of the server (rds) instance.

One way to do it, if you don't want to set up certificates, is to setting the sslMode to `require` `allow` or `prefer`. See https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/#connection-parameters and https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/ssl/#configuring-the-client.

So your jdbc url would be: `jdbc:postgresql://<host>/<db_name>?sslmode=prefer`

Answer (score 0):

In my use case, I saw this exact same error, while testing connectivity with a Postgres endpoint that **didn't** use encrypted connection.

Resolution:
I modified the endpoint to require SSL. Just this, and it connected successfully.